# keep track of logged in users

Tags: php, authentication

I'm designing an application in PHP, something like a users directory, where i need to display login status for each user. Is there a safe way to tell if a user is connected (logged in) or not?

Edit: I'm updating the post with some application logic. The application is about a craftsmen directory. Each craftsman will login to the application. When someone search for craftsmen, he will be able to see the logged in ones and send a message with a job description that needs to be done.
Craftsmen may not have other activity that just log in to the app, so the app it self must have a way to "tell" if a user is logged in or not.

Comment: Probably, depends a bit what safe means.

Comment: You could maybe try checking the time since their last activity (by storing such data) and if that is less then a certain number (maybe 5, 10 or 20 minutes) list them as a logged in user. Aside from that you could also get the client-side of all your pages to constantly 'ping' the server to let you know they are active as opposed to just the last page load.

Comment: @Stathis: It depends on your application need/feature. Whatever you want you can do but the coding should be in an secure way. Displaying and all depends on your requirement only.

Comment: @VinothBabu I'm not sure i understand your comment. Basically i need to display only connected (logged in) users. The application logic is about craftsman that they are connected to the app, thus ready to respond to any calls, so i need to be sure that a user is actually connected to the application in order to display him. Is there a "keep alive" technique i could use to achieve that? Maybe the app could periodically (every few seconds) send some requests to the server to keep the user alive?

Comment: I think that chat applications (should) work in a simmilar way, but i cannot think of it.

Answer (score 1):

I think only php for your requirements would make it difficult. Take a look at [socket.io](http://socket.io) or something similar. You could achieve this with craftsmen having a connection like longpolling/sse/websockets. You can integrate this with php serving the html and then set up a connection from the client on document ready to socket.io.

Comment: Yes, socket.io is a way to do it but it needs Node.js platform to run and that makes it a bit unhandy, because the main app will run on a PHP/Apache/mySQL environment. Good suggestion though!

Comment: For what its worth: you can install it next to php/apache/mysql, with a reverse proxy (mod_proxy on apache) you can even access it on the same domain: say io.example.com maps to example.com/io/ for example to avoid cross domain issues. It might seem intimidating but it's really not that difficult and it would fit your needs much better on the long run.

Comment: I think your suggestion is a way to do it, i'm giving you a positive feedback for that.

Answer (score 0):

By "safe" do you mean "accurate" ?

I'd suggest setting a flag to `LOGGED_IN` when they initially, and successfully (being safe!), log-in. Then update a timestamp each time this user requests another page. When the `last_update` reaches a grace period, 15 minutes?, you can then assume they've logged out.

Comment: Yes, but this does not provide a really sure way to know if they are connected. Please check my other comments. App users may be just logged in (and inactive) and waiting for a message/call, because of the application logic i described.